# How to wrap 2 linear layouts and a relative one with ScrollView?

Tags: android, scrollview

Before adding the Scrollview, my layout looks pretty well on different devices. What I have are 2 images, on one row, and a checkbox on the top right corner of each of them. When I add the ScrollView, however, the check-boxes move away and the images appear below them. Below is the code so far:

```
    <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fadeScrollbars="false"
            android:fillViewport="true"
            android:orientation="vertical">
    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/linLay"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">


<!--ROW 1 -->
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dip"
            android:id="@+id/parentLayout"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/img1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp" />

                <CheckBox
                    android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:text=""
                    android:background="@android:color/white"/>



            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1">


                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/img2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp" />

                <CheckBox
                    android:id="@+id/checkBox2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:text=""
                    android:background="@android:color/white"/>

            </RelativeLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

    <!--Row2-->
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/img3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp" />

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/checkBox3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:text=""
                android:background="@android:color/white"/>
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/img4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="1" />

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/checkBox4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:text=""
                android:background="@android:color/white"/>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: The scrollview tag is not even closed - so it should not even compile

Comment: Just there are more rows to follow, in the original code it's closed :)

Answer (score 0):

You can make another xml and have it included in your scroll view using the include layout tag. Create new scrolling activity in android studio to see and example of the same.

Comment: I was trying but can't implement your suggestion. May you give me a code example? Thank you!

Comment: This is not an answer to the question and should have been a comment rather than an answer

Answer (score 0):

Problem is with the weight parameter in the items in each row. As suggested by sanket pahuja, I split the file in 2. One with the item, and another with the layout like this.

item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="60dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text=""
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

And the other is layout_scroll

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fadeScrollbars="false"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/linLay"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">


        <!--ROW 1 -->
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dip"
            android:id="@+id/parentLayout"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp">
            <include layout="@layout/item1"/>
            <include layout="@layout/item1"/>
            </LinearLayout>
        <!--ROW 1 -->
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dip"
            android:id="@+id/parentLayout2"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp">
            <include layout="@layout/item1"/>
            <include layout="@layout/item1"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

You can check that it works great. But it you add weight=1 to the item1.xml relative layout, the checkbox moves away as the layout tries to get the whole space.

Comment: Still doesn't work, unfortunately. The visualization is the same - the checkboxes appear in a row, the images under them. I need the boxes to be in the top right corners of the images

Comment: They appear to me that way. Which android studio version are you using? and sdk?